# Is Drools SubFlow/SubProcess used much at all? Drools documentation lacking

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I'm trying to prototype a workflow using a rule flow and rules. I started testing subProcess because it's obviously useful to be able to call or reuse a subroutine. After much fiddling, I can't get out-mapping to work as expected (as well as I can manage from the lack of detailed documentations).

So I started searching for more examples. Bafflingly, I only managed to locate one example (in the jbossrules checkout) that uses subProcess - and that one doesn't even bother doing any in-out mapping at all. Every other mapping related examples are done via WorkItems.

Are subProcesses much less useful than WorkItems? Not that I fully understand their differences...

I think I better get a book, considering the lack of online resources (would really appreciate if someone can recommend a good site or a good book). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would really appreciate any improvements you could make to the documentation.  But apparently, the documentation regarding sub process mapping isn't that bad, as you managed to specify it correctly (the error was in the action node in the sub process) ;)

There is an example of a sub process using out mappings in the junit tests as well:
http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/integrationtests/ProcessSubProcessTest.java